# C What kind of sorting algorithm is this?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, strcmp

I decompiled a application and found what seems like some kind of sorting algorithm I just don't know which one it is can someone let me know it's actual name?

whatever is passed into the strcmpi wrapper is in some area's divided by 2 who knows some crazy stuff.. I thought it was qsort (quicksort) since it's a standard library for C. But i'm not sure.

```
int __cdecl SomeKindOfSortAlgorithm(int a1, int a2, int a3, signed int a4, int (__cdecl *a5)(unsigned int, unsigned int), int a6)
{
  int v6; // esi@1
  int result; // eax@1
  int v8; // ebp@2
  int v9; // edi@2

  v6 = 0;
  result = 0;
  *(unsigned int *)a6 = 0;
  if ( !a3 )
    return result;
  v8 = a2;
  v9 = a2 + a4 * (a3 - 1);
  if ( a2 > (unsigned int)v9 )
  {
LABEL_9:
    if ( result > 0 )
      v6 += a4;
    return v6;
  }
  while ( 1 )
  {
    v6 = v8 + a4 * (v9 - v8) / a4 / 2;
    result = a5(a1, v8 + a4 * (v9 - v8) / a4 / 2);
    if ( result < 0 )
    {
      if ( v6 == a2 )
        goto LABEL_9;
      v9 = v6 - a4;
      goto LABEL_8;
    }
    if ( result <= 0 )
      break;
    v8 = v6 + a4;
LABEL_8:
    if ( v8 > (unsigned int)v9 )
      goto LABEL_9;
  }
  *(unsigned int *)a6 = 1;
  if ( v6 == a2 )
  {
LABEL_15:
    result = a2;
  }
  else
  {
    while ( 1 )
    {
      v6 -= a4;
      if ( a5(a1, v6) )
        break;
      if ( v6 == a2 )
        goto LABEL_15;
    }
    result = v6 + a4;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here is the compare function

```
int __cdecl StrCmpiWrapper(const char *Str1, const char **a2)
{
  return _strcmpi(Str1, *a2);
}
```

Here is how you use it.

```
  int ChatMsgBuffer;
  int v4; // eax@1
  int v5; // eax@5
  int v8; // [sp+10h] [bp-4h]@1

  v4 = SomeKindOfSortAlgorithm(
         ChatMsgBuffer,
         textFile->Pointer,
         textFile->TotalElements,
         4,
         (int (__cdecl *)(unsigned int, unsigned int))StrCmpiWrapper,
         (int)&v8);

  if ( !v8 && v4 )
  {
      //Allocate memory .. copy it and other stuff here.
  }
```

Here is how bsearch C standard looks like decompiled

```
int __cdecl bsearch(int a1, int a2, unsigned int a3, int a4, int (__cdecl *a5)(_DWORD, _DWORD))
{
  unsigned int v5; // ebx@1
  int v6; // eax@2

  v5 = a3;
  if ( !a3 )
    return 0;
  while ( 1 )
  {
    v6 = a5(a1, a2 + (v5 >> 1) * a4);
    if ( v6 < 0 )
    {
      v5 >>= 1;
      goto LABEL_6;
    }
    if ( !v6 )
      return a2 + (v5 >> 1) * a4;
    a2 += (v5 >> 1) * a4 + a4;
    v5 = v5 - (v5 >> 1) - 1;
LABEL_6:
    if ( !v5 )
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer could be found at : https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/c-what-kind-of-sorting-algorithm-is-this/

Comment: This is probably off-topic here. Instead, I would consider asking over at the [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange site](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I figured to post it here since it's compilable I think, only problem is those LABELS make it difficult to figure out what it does exactly. I guess I'll post it there.

Comment: But clearly you're using a decompiler, and doing reverse engineering, not software development, per se.  I'm not voting to close, but don't be surprised if others do, or if you see no responses.

Comment: I usually figure out my problems by googling code / hexadecimal values and I figured it would help to find it quick on stackoverflow in the future.

Comment: But Stack Overflow is not a site for *reverse engineering*. Unsurprisingly, that is *exactly* what the Reverse Engineering site is for. Have you even looked at it?! I think you'll find it more appropriate than Stack Overflow which is for *software development*.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Why would this be off-topic here, what's the reason? I don't find one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Just because there's another, probably better SE site (even if it wasn't beta), does not make this off-topic at SO.

Comment: @user3435580 I'd try to convert those `goto`s into usual loops, probably with help of break and continue. That might make it clearer.

Comment: [You shouldn't cross-post to multiple SE sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Keep in mind that questions should not make an attempt at answering the question (beyond the research attempt you put in before asking the question). If you have something to add not covered in one of the answers, feel free to leave a comment somewhere (as you already did), or post an answer of your own. I'm also not sure where the `bsearch` decompiled code fits in though (if you read your question top to bottom, you should see it's sort of out of place) - if the idea is to point out the similarity between that and the unknown code, you should elaborate and post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a binary search to me. Note that there isn't any swapping of items, so it's unlikely to be a sort. Looks like it's finding the first occurrence of the string `a1`, or where `a1` would be inserted, in a sorted array of strings.

Note the expression:

```
v6 = v8 + a4 * (v9 - v8) / a4 / 2;
```

This is finding the midpoint between `v8` and `v9`. Then you have a call to the string comparison, and different behavior based on whether the comparison result is less, equal, or greater.

Comment: Thank you i'll try to decompile a binary search program to see if it matches up. Don't those binary searches work on sorted arrays only?

Comment: I posted decompiled code below how the bsearch looks like decompiled from `stdlib.h` I couldn't even find the number 2 or division anywhere in it. Could be just because I used a different compiler.

Comment: Found my answer you are correct Jim Mischel, http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/c-what-kind-of-sorting-algorithm-is-this/4140?noredirect=1#4140

Comment: @user3435580: The reason you didn't find a divide by two in the bsearch code is because it's hidden behind a right shift. For example, this line: `a2 += (v5 >> 1) * a4 + a4;`. The expression `v5 >> 1` does the same thing as `v5 / 2`.